# Why container restart policy is defined in Pod specification?

Tags: kubernetes

Does anyone know why `restartPolicy` field is defined on the Pod level instead of the container level?

It would seem that this setting is more closely related to the container, not the Pod.

Then how to controll restart policy of single container in multi-container Pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **restart policy** is part of the **POD** spec.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: 1st
    image: image-1
    command: ["./bash", "-test1"]
  - name: 2nd
    image: image-2
    command: ["./bash", "-test2"]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Restart policy gets set the at **POD spec** level, and get applied to all the containers in **POD** even if **init container** is there.

If there are **multi containers** inside the **POD**, we have to consider those as **tightly coupled**.

**Official documents says something like this** : [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#workload-resources-for-managing-pods)

> Pods that run multiple containers that need to work together. A Pod can encapsulate an application composed of multiple co-located
> containers that are tightly coupled and need to share resources. These
> co-located containers form a single cohesive unit of service—for
> example, one container serving data stored in a shared volume to the
> public, while a separate sidecar container refreshes or updates those
> files. The Pod wraps these containers, storage resources, and an
> ephemeral network identity together as a single unit.

> Note: Grouping multiple co-located and co-managed containers in a
> single Pod is a relatively advanced use case. You should use this
> pattern only in specific instances in which your containers are
> tightly coupled.

If you want to restart the **single container** in **POD** you won't be able to do it, you have keep that container out of **POD** then by **POD** design.

Even if you will see the [container restart policy](https://You%20can%27t%20restart%20single%20containers%20in%20a%20pod%20by%20design.%20Just%20move%20the%20container%20out%20into%20it%27s%20own%20pod) it's talk about the : **POD spec** restart policy only.